# How to set a div position to depend on another div position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the html part of the code:

```
<div class="snake">
    <div class="body"></div>
</div>
```

The function below takes the last block, removes it and creates another one to put it at the top.

```
//The snake turns right
var turnRight = function() {
    blocks_moved++;
    $('.snake').children().last().remove();
    $('<div></div>').addClass('body').prependTo('.snake').css('top', 0 + '%').css('left', xPos * blocks_moved * 1.2 + '%');
    $('.snake').children().removeClass('head');
    $('.snake').children().first().addClass('head');
...more code
```

With the code below I tried to set the snake position eqal to head's position so every time a new block becomes the head the snake moves by one block.

```
//Set the snake position equal to head's position
var headPos = $('.snake').children().first().position();
    $('.snake').position(headPos);

        if (blocks_moved === length) {
            blocks_moved === 0;
        }
    }
```

When I call the function `turnRight();` the head and body move but snake stays in place. I also tried with `.css()` method but I didn't succeed. Any other ways to do this?

I solved this problem with .offset() and positioning. Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/dusth7gc/3/

Comment: Could you provide a live example in http://jsfiddle.net or something?

Comment: Kind of need to see a demo to see what is happening (you can do this straight on stackoverflow now). Can you inspect the snake and see if any css is being applied?

Comment: I solved this but thanks anyway

Comment: It would be great if you give it a minute to share your answer.. So you can help other people who have the same issue as yours..

Comment: This is the fiddle for the full game. It still has some bugs and some things should be improved but this is basically it. It's not very clear but I hope it would help somehow. https://jsfiddle.net/dusth7gc/3/

Comment: Please post your solution so it can be accepted as **the** answer.  Helps clean up the unanswered cue and other posters with the same or similar issues. @js-m

Comment: You should consider using a game framework like PhaserJS... You will trigger a complete window refresh each time you you do DOM manipulation like prepend() or append(), if you're wondering why your code is running slowly. At least try to limit it :)

Comment: Answer your question and check it as the correct answer for others to know and empty the unanswered stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this problem with .offset() and positioning.

```
var turnRight = function() {

    $('.body').css('background-color', 'gray');

    headPos_x = ($('.head').offset().left / $(window).width() * 100);
    headPos_y = ($('.head').offset().top / $(window).height() * 100);  

    $('<div></div>').addClass('body').prependTo('.snake').css('top', headPos_y + '%').css('left', headPos_x + helper_width * 1.2 + '%');

            $('.snake').children().last().remove();
            $('.snake').children().removeClass('head');
            $('.snake').children().first().addClass('head');



            $('.helper').css('top', $('.head').offset().top + 'px').css('left',$('.head').offset().left + 'px');

        if(collision($('.helper'), $('.meal')) === true) {
            $('.meal').remove();
            $('<div></div>').addClass('body').css('background-color', 'transparent').appendTo('.snake');
            foodCreate();
        }
}
```

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/dusth7gc/3/.